# Generic Entity validation for all properties with type string in Symfony

Tags: symfony, symfony-validator

I was wondering if there is some solution to the problem I will now say.

I have plenty of entities in the project (Symfony 4.4) and I need some generic solution to validate max length of all properties that have type="string" instead of going individually to each property and define Length validator (it would take a lot of time for that). So the whole process would look like this: Generic entity validation that goes through all the related entity properties -> picks up the properties that are text type with length definition -> validates the actual property value against the length definition.

Comment: if i understant correctly you want to use orm length into the validator ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can acheive that directly via your validation.yml, this feature is introduced in SF 4.3

```
# Enables validator auto-mapping support.
# For instance, basic validation constraints will be inferred from Doctrine's metadata.
#auto_mapping:
#    App\Entity\: []
```